# Какой сериализатор выбрать?

Tags: java

Нужен сериализатор в xml файлы. Не знаю, какой использовать.
Нужен максимально простой в работе и не XStream.

Вообще нужно будет реализовать как сериализацию класса, так и десерилизацию.

Различные парсеры не нужно - нужен готовый сериализатор.

Нужно, чтобы сериализация и выполнялась так, чтобы в xml файле лежало что-то такое:
http://www.solarix.ru/pix/faind/datamining/xml_file_example.gif

Соответственно и десериализация должна с таким же файлом работать

Comment: для каких целей? почему не json?

Comment: нужно просто сериализовать класс в xml

Comment: А чем XStream не устроил? Пользовался и им и JAXB, особенной разницы не почувствовал, в конечном счете принципы одни и те же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html), входит в состав JDK начиная с версии 1.6 кажется. Довольно прост в использовании.

Comment: А получится сделать так, чтобы сериализованный класс в xml файле выглядел вот так:
http://www.solarix.ru/pix/faind/datamining/xml_file_example.gif

Comment: не вижу никаких проблем

Comment: ага, нашел парочку неплохих примеров... очень все просто - спасибо большое!!!
А можете еще что-нибудь посоветовать?
НУ просто, чтобы сравнить..

Comment: ну еще например http://dom4j.sourceforge.net

Comment: Так это же парсер, а мне сериализатор нужен..